# Re-position of contents after uncover of other contents

Tags: beamer, listings, minipage

**Updated:**

Considering the following latex document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
  \frametitle{Implementing FA}
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{l | c | c |}
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\ \cline{2-3}
      S & \onslide<2->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<3->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      T & \onslide<4->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<5->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      U & \onslide<6->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<7->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{onlyenv}<9->
\begin{lstlisting}
i = 0;
state = 0;

while (input[i])
{
  state = A[state,input[i++]];
}
\end{lstlisting}
        \end{onlyenv}
      \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As soon as slide 9 is unconvered, the table on the first(left) minipage is relocated. How can one forbid this?

Comment: Please make your example compilable

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `t` (top alignment) option for the `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Implementing FA}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c |}
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\ \cline{2-3}
      S & \onslide<2->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<3->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      T & \onslide<4->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<5->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      U & \onslide<6->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<7->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{onlyenv}<9->
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
i = 0;
state = 0;

while (input[i])
{
  state = A[state,input[i++]];
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Same idea, but with the native `columns` and `\column` commands (essentially internally it will translate to `minipage`s):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{Implementing FA}

\begin{columns}
\column[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c |}
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} \\ \cline{2-3}
      S & \onslide<2->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<3->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      T & \onslide<4->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<5->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
      U & \onslide<6->{\textcolor{blue}{T}}  & \onslide<7->{\textcolor{blue}{U}}  \\ \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\column[t]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{onlyenv}<9->
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
i = 0;
state = 0;

while (input[i])
{
  state = A[state,input[i++]];
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```